# How to get cumulative total users but ignoring the users who already appear in previous day? using bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I want to calculate cumulative users per day but if the users exist is previous days they will not counted.

```
date_key      user_id
2022-01-01     001
2022-01-01     002
2022-01-02     001
2022-01-02     003
2022-01-03     002
2022-01-03     003
2022-01-04     002
2022-01-04     004
```

on daily basis we can get

```
date_key     total_user
2022-01-01      2
2022-01-02      2
2022-01-03      2
2022-01-04      2
```

if we simply calculate cumulative we can get 2,4,6,8 for each day the goal is to get the table like this

```
date_key     total_user
2022-01-01      2
2022-01-02      3
2022-01-03      3
2022-01-04      4
```

im using this query to get the result, since the data is really2 huge. the query takes forever to complete.

```
select b.date_key,count(distinct a.user_id) total_user
from t1 a
join t1 b 
   on b.date_key >= a.date_key 
   and date_trunc(a.date_key,month) = date_trunc(b.date_key,month)
group by 1
order by 1
```

and yes the calculation should be on reset when the month is changing.

and btw I'm using google bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number each user's appearance by order of date. Count only the ones seen for the first time:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by date_trunc(date_key, month), userid
                           order by date_key) as rn
    from T
)
select date_key,
    sum(count(case when rn = 1 then 1 end)) -- or countif(rn = 1)
        over (partition by date_trunc(date_key, month)
              order by date_key) as cum_monthly_users
from data
group by date_key;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dc426d79a7786fc8a5b25a22f0755e27

Comment: i really don't think it produces expected result! :o(

Comment: @muhnandap I had inadvertently filtered out dates where all of the users had been previously counted. You'll want to adjust your code accordingly as I've corrected the query.

Comment: yes, I think this is what I saw in your original answer - for example `2022-01-03      3` entry was missing. sorry for noising, but looks like this helped in fixing the answer :o)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. cumulative total users but ignoring the users who already appear in previous day?
> 2. the calculation should be on reset when the month is changing
> 3. the data is really2 huge

Consider below approach

```
select date_key, 
  ( select hll_count.merge(u) 
    from unnest(users) u
  ) as total_user
from (
  select date_key, date_trunc(date(date_key), month) year_month,
    array_agg(users) over(partition by date_trunc(date(date_key), month) order by date_key) users
  from (
    select date_key, hll_count.init(user_id) users
    from your_table
    group by date_key
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: not [obviously] above ##1 and 2 are met - and output as expected, but also here we use [HyperLogLog++ functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions) which will effectivelly address above #3

> > HLL++ functions are approximate aggregate functions. Approximate aggregation typically requires less memory than exact aggregation functions, like COUNT(DISTINCT), but also introduces statistical error. This makes HLL++ functions appropriate for large data streams for which linear memory usage is impractical, as well as for data that is already approximate.