# Cumulative sum of distinct users over time grouped by categories

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
WITH orders AS
      (SELECT '1234' as user_id, '12340' as order_id, DATE(2021, 01, 05) as date
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234A', DATE(2022, 01, 07)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234B', DATE(2022, 02, 10)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234C', DATE(2022, 02, 11)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234D', DATE(2022, 03, 21)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234E', DATE(2022, 06, 23)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234F', DATE(2022, 07, 01)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234G', DATE(2022, 08, 04)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234H', DATE(2022, 08, 08)
        UNION ALL SELECT '1234', '1234I', DATE(2022, 10, 23)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456A', DATE(2022, 01, 11)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456B', DATE(2022, 02, 23)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456C', DATE(2022, 03, 08)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456D', DATE(2022, 03, 15)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456E', DATE(2022, 07, 19)
        UNION ALL SELECT '456', '456F', DATE(2022, 08, 12)
      )
```

I'd like to be able to:

1. group these users into buckets defined by their number of orders over time
2. count the distinct number of user in each bucket over time

The first step would be to get the cumulative sum of orders for each user over time with something like this `COUNT(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) AS cumul_orders`. Then based on this new cumul_orders column I can bucket my users into different categories depending on their number of orders at x date using a case formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN cumul_purchases = 1 THEN 'bucket_1'
  WHEN cumul_purchases = 2 THEN 'bucket_2'
  WHEN cumul_purchases = 3 THEN 'bucket_3'
  WHEN cumul_purchases >= 4 THEN 'bucket_4_more'
```

Then I'm stuck because I have to count the distinct number of users into each bucket for each date...

**edit #1**

This is the intermediate output I'm being stuck with. From there I need to be able to count to total numbers of distinct users at any given time for each bucket.
[image]

**edit #2**

This is (I think!) the output I want:

```
Date            bucket                value     
2022/01/01      'bucket_1'            0
2022/01/01      'bucket_2'            0
2022/01/01      'bucket_3'            0
2022/01/01      'bucket_4_more'       0
2022/01/02      'bucket_1'            0
2022/01/02      'bucket_2'            0
2022/01/02      'bucket_3'            0
2022/01/02      'bucket_4_more'       0
...
2022/01/07      'bucket_1'            1
2022/01/07      'bucket_2'            0
2022/01/07      'bucket_3'            0
2022/01/07      'bucket_4_more'       0
...
2022/01/11      'bucket_1'            2
2022/01/11      'bucket_2'            0
2022/01/11      'bucket_3'            0
2022/01/11      'bucket_4_more'       0
2022/01/12      'bucket_1'            2
2022/01/12      'bucket_2'            0
2022/01/12      'bucket_3'            0
2022/01/12      'bucket_4_more'       0
...
2022/06/01      'bucket_1'            0
2022/06/01      'bucket_2'            0
2022/06/01      'bucket_3'            0
2022/06/01      'bucket_4_more'       2
```

at each date, a user is classified in a bucket based on the cumulative numbers of orders he has made and each distinct users is counted in each bucket.

Comment: Adding desired output helps a lot

Comment: Hi @Simon Breton, Can you try adding the line `count(distinct user_id) over(partition by purchase_count_bucket) distinct_user_count`  in your query? Can you provide sample output?

Comment: we need solid example of expected output (based on input data already presented in question). then i feel it is relatively simple "challenge", so you will get answer promptly :o)

Comment: I've updated my question is the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is direction for you to explore

```
select date, bucket, 
  (select count(distinct user_id) from t.users user_id) as value
from (
  select *, array_agg(user_id) over(partition by bucket order by date) users
  from temp
) t
```

Comment: also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/73546428/5221944 address potential performance or memory issues